# Duplicate target after "pod install"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, xcode-workspace

After I added new dependency to my project and run `pod install`, I have duplicate target in my workspace(.xcworkspace) as below:

[image]

And this is the pod file structure:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.6'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'SocketRocket'
```

I restart the project and also Xcode, but it does not help. What is the reason and how can I solve the problem?

Comment: Can you show your podfile structure?

Comment: Have you tried removing and re-running pod install ? Did it have the same effect ?

Comment: Delete your .xcworkspace, podfile.lock and pods folder and try again pod install.

Comment: @alex I add it to question

Comment: @userx  I want to find the reason too, because many of my project have the same problem in XCode 8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, try to wrap your pods with target specification, like this:

```
target 'TargetName' do
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics' 
  #other pods 
end
```

2. Delete your .xcworkspace, podfile.lock and pods folder, just as  @SukruK suggested.
3. Do `pod install` again and open the workspace created.

You can do the following instructions in order to fix this configuration issue `CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set.`

1. Go to your project settings
2. Set `None` configuration set for both Pods-related targets
3. Run `pod install` again

[image]

Comment: It does not help with error: [!] CocoaPods did not set the base configuration of your project because your project already has a custom config set. In order for CocoaPods integration to work at all, please either set the base configurations of the target `XXX` to `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXX/Pods-mothera_socket.debug.xcconfig` or include the `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-XXX_socket/Pods-XXX.debug.xcconfig` in your build configuration.

Comment: @SoheilNovinfard See the updated unswer, it should help.

Comment: I am also facing almost same issue. Instead of duplicating the folder, its duplicating the files in my case. I cannot delete the pod.lock because when I run the pod install , it will install the latest version of existing library. Since I use the different version of Alamofire, it will cause other error. How will I solve it ?