# Duplicate of files shown in Project Navigator in Xcode

Tags: xcode9.4

All files for my workspace appear twice in the Project Navigator (Xcode 9.4.1) but if I delete one from the project (only deleting the reference), both disappear and if I add a file it gets added twice.[image: duplicate references]

I have not found a question with the same issue. I may have to create a complete new workspace but I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This post is similar: [Duplicate target after "pod install"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39961447/duplicate-target-after-pod-install)

In Finder, if you Show package contents of your .xcworkspace file and then view contents.xcworkspacedata, you'll see a duplicate in that file.

To fix, delete your .xcworkspace, podfile.lock and pods folder and do "pod install" again...

Comment: Thanks, this works, I was hoping to be able to fix it without the delete.

Comment: me too. its scary!

Comment: The problem is resolved with this. Thanks.